# Visual Studio Merge Changes In Merge Tool Missing

Tags: visual-studio, merge

I taken branched from master branch. While I work on branch, other developers worked on master branch. While merge operation branch to master branch, i saw multiple conflicts. I wanted manual merge but missing "Merge Changes In Merge Tool". There are just Keep Target Branch Version and Take Source Branch Version buttons. What can i do for issue?

PS : This issue, there are just .cs files.

Answer (score 1):

If it's only for .cs files merging would probably been disabled.
In Visual Studio go to Team Explorer > Settings
Under section Team Project Collection > Source Control you can manage file extensions an the enabling of file merging.